# Null and empty check in one go in groovy

Tags: groovy

Can someone please clarify below issue.

Below validation throw NULL pointer error when pass null in myVar. It is because of `!myVar.isEmpty()`

```
if (myVar!= null || !myVar.isEmpty() ) {
             
             some code///
                }
```

Below works though as expected,

```
if (myVar!= null) {
        if (!myVar.isEmpty()) {
             some code///

                }
```

Any other way of having both steps together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `.isEmpty()` is used on a string, then you can also just use Groovy
"truth" directly, as `null` and also empty strings are "false".

```
[null, "", "ok"].each{
    if (it) {
        println it
    }
}
// -> ok
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( myVar!= null && !myVar.isEmpty() ) {
    //some code
}
```

the same as

```
if ( !( myVar== null || myVar.isEmpty() ) ) {
    //some code
}
```

and to make it shorter - it's better to add method like `hasValues`

then check could be like this:

```
if( myVar?.hasValues() ){
    //code
}
```

and finally to make it groovier - create a method `boolean asBoolean()`

```
class MyClass{
    String s=""
    boolean isEmpty(){
        return s==null || s.length()==0
    }
    boolean asBoolean(){
        return !isEmpty()
    }
}

def myVar = new MyClass(s:"abc")

//in this case your check could be veeery short
//the following means myVar!=null && myVar.asBoolean()==true
if(myVar) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: In the above case when pass myVar as NULL it go inside the code. Because second check `!myVar.isEmpty()` gives this `Cannot invoke method isEmpty() on null object`

Comment: @SMPH Not in any sane programming language, because `if` is short-circuiting

Comment: @SMPH, i've updated an answer. and for your comment: i'm using `&&` to join expressions `a!=null && !a.isEmpty()`. in case when `a=null` the first part returns `false` and it's not necessary to execute the second part because `false && any` returns false. so groovy (and all other languages) are not executing the second part after `&&` if first one returns `false`